# I want to set an icon for date picker

Tags: jquery

I want to set an icon for date picker I tried so many time but I can't do it please help me.

Here is my date picker function

```
 $(function() {
 $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,     
  changeYear: true,
  depth: "year",
  showOn: 'both',      
  buttonImage:'../../ui/image/calender.png',
  buttonImageOnly: true
 });
});
```

Comment: what datepiker are you using?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/1z63c9d5/ this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the default datepicker widget (jQueryUI) have a look at [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage) , showOn, buttonImage and buttonImageOnly options do the work.
Be sure the path points to the correct image file.

Comment: this could be a comment rather an answer

Comment: @DipaliVasani I don't know hot to add link in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your icon path. I am 100% sure your icon path is not correct:

```
$(function() {
 $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,     
  changeYear: true,
  depth: "year",
  showOn: 'both',      
  buttonImage:'../../ui/image/calender.png', // Please check it
  buttonImageOnly: true
 });
});
```

../../ui/image/calender.png means

you have to go 2 folders back from current position ( Current Page Position ) then go to "ui" folder then go to "image" folder then search for calender.png